# How to get the user actions?

Tags: javascript, integration, dundas

I have integrated Dundas BI viewer in my application using `iframe`, I followed the sample given in official docs. I can able to see the dashboard in my app.

from `javascript.override.js` I can override javascript and get Dundas Object but I didn't find any events to subscribe to catch user actions.

I wanted to get the user interaction(DOM Events), is there any way to catch the interaction events with the appropriate data?

Answer (score 2):

Dundas BI offers many user events, so I think it's more about which ones you want to catch. For example, if you have a chart named `chart1` and you want to catch the 'click' event through javascript, you can do it via the `ready` action with the following script:

```
$(chart1).bind(dundas.view.controls.AdapterConstants.clickEventName, function (e) {
  // here you can access e to get various information about the click event,
  //including the original jQuery event under e.originalEvent.
});
```

To get the related data at some x,y point (such as from the above example e.originalEvent), you can use something like this:

```
var jQevent = e.originalEvent;
var relatedData = chart1.getContext({
"position": {
  "e": jQevent,
  "left": jQevent.offsetX,
  "top": jQevent.offsetY
}
});
```

Remember that at any time you can also access the data that's currently on the control through:

```
chart1.metricSetBindings[0].dataResult.cellset
```

For more information you can see many script examples here:
http://www.dundas.com/support/support-center/support-articles/scripting/

And the JavaScript API docs can be found here:
http://www.dundas.com/support/api-docs/js/

Comment: I would like to have it in generic way, Lets say a dashboard contains 10 controls like table, chart, etc... I dont want to handle each control differently,  if there is any single event of dashboard that handles click on any control of dashboard, and should fire given callback with appropriate data. suppose use clicked on a table row, the dashboard event should fire with the data like {control:table1, action:rowSelection, rowData: {...}}.

Comment: No, there's no generic event because there's no generic DOM bubbling of events from elements which don't have a child->parent relationship.